# Seg fault when using c++0x initializer list

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, c++11, initializer-list

I get a seg fault when I use the c++0x initializer list with a vector. I can't figure out why it is happening. My debugger says that the crash happens at this function in the standard library:

```
  template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
    inline void
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
// Allow perfect forwarding
_Construct(_T1* __p, _T2&& __value)
#else
_Construct(_T1* __p, const _T2& __value)
#endif
{
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // 402. wrong new expression in [some_]allocator::construct
  ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(_GLIBCXX_FORWARD(_T2, __value));
}
```

I've tried to determine the purpose of this function but I can't find any explanation/documentation online.

The code that uses the initializer list in my code goes like this:

```
bool Cube::ProcessData(MeshData* data)
{
    data->Clear();

    data->v =
    {
        Vec3(.5,-.5,-.5), Vec3(.5,-.5,.5), Vec3(-.5,-.5,.5), Vec3(-.5,-.5,-.5),
        Vec3(.5, .5,-.5), Vec3(.5, .5,.5), Vec3(-.5, .5,.5), Vec3(-.5, .5,-.5)
    };
...
}
```

The data structure that gets passed to this function gets created here:

```
    template <class ProcessorT, class DataT, typename... Args>
    const DataT* DataManager::RequestData(Args... args)
    {
        MutexLock lock(*mutex);

        Request req;

        data_cache.PushBack();
        req.data      = &data_cache.GetBack();
        req.processor = new ProcessorT(args...);
        request_list.push_back(req);

        return static_cast<DataT*>(req.data);
    }
```

The data_cache structure is my own list class I use to avoid copying. The ProcessData function gets called on a different thread than the one the data structure is created on.

And this is the debugger output for the call stack:

```
#0 004FAAD6 _Construct<UtilityLib::TVec3<float>, UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const&>(this=0x104aba0, __first=0x593fb98, __last=0x593fbf8) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:80)
#1 00000000 uninitialized_copy<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*, UtilityLib::TVec3<float>*>(this=0x104aba0, __first=0x593fb98, __last=0x593fbf8) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:74)
#2 00000000 uninitialized_copy<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*, UtilityLib::TVec3<float>*>(this=0x104aba0, __first=0x593fb98, __last=0x593fbf8) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:116)
#3 00000000 __uninitialized_copy_a<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*, UtilityLib::TVec3<float>*, UtilityLib::TVec3<float> >(this=0x104aba0, __first=0x593fb98, __last=0x593fbf8) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:318)
#4 00000000 std::vector<UtilityLib::TVec3<float>, std::allocator<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> > >::_M_assign_aux<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*>(this=0x104aba0, __first=0x593fb98, __last=0x593fbf8) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:260)
#5 004127B3 _M_assign_dispatch<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*>(this=0x6e8af18, data=0x104ab98) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1065)
#6 00000000 assign<UtilityLib::TVec3<float> const*>(this=0x6e8af18, data=0x104ab98) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:396)
#7 00000000 operator=(this=0x6e8af18, data=0x104ab98) (c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:359)
#8 00000000 GameEngine::Render3D::Cube::ProcessData(this=0x6e8af18, data=0x104ab98) (C:\CodeBlocksProjects\GameEngine\src\Primitives.cpp:56)
```

I suspect that my list class might be the culprit but even if it is I would not know why. Hopefully someone on StackOverflow can help me understand this problem. I appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Psst: Use perfect forwarding for `ProcessorT` args: `RequestData(Args&&... args)` and `new ProcessorT(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`, `#include <utility>`.

Comment: @Ken: "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc" hints at GCC.

Comment: My compiler is MinGW/g++

Comment: @Xeo: GCC is great, but versions are generally nice to know as well!

Comment: @Ken: "c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/**4.5.2**/" - :P

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, whooops, don't know how I missed that one!

Comment: What does MeshData::Clear() do to `v`?

Comment: @KennyTM: MeshData has a vector for vertices, texture coordinates, normals and face indices. MeshData::Clear() just calls the clear function of each vector.

Comment: Is the crash consistently reproducible or is it sporadic?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the most difficult bugs are usually the dumbest.

The problem was that I was allocating memory for the Base class, not the Derived. I called new for this structure:

```
    class Data
    {
    public:
        enum State { LOADED, UNLOADED, FAILED };
        Data();
        virtual ~Data();
        State state;
    };
```

When I should have been allocating memory for this one:

```
    struct MeshData : public Data
    {
        vector<Vec3>    v, n;
        vector<Vec2>    u;
        vector<Polygon> p;

        MeshData();
        ~MeshData();
        void Clear();
        string Str()      const;
        string StrStats() const;

        bool IsValid() const;
        bool IsValid(bool& has_n, bool& has_u, bool& all_tri) const;
};
```

so whenever I try to access an instance of MeshData, I was accessing memory outside the bounds of the structure.

So I was correct in assuming my List class was the culprit (sort of). I have added a means to specify the type for allocation:

```
template <typename TT, typename... Args> void PushBackT(Args... args);
```

I'd like to thank everyone who helped with this problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so removing it from the list of open questions and earning a badge :-).

Answer (score 0):

While you are designating the return a type of `RequestData` as a `const DataT*`, the pointer you're passing to your `ProcessData` function is not constant anymore, and you're calling methods in `ProcessData` that modify the object being pointed to.  This points to an underlying problem in your program design where in one function you're returning pointers to constant objects, but then obviously casting away the constant nature of the pointer in other functions and threads in order to change the underlying object.

In order to properly maintain the `const`-ness of data, it's generally a good idea to return `const T&` for a reference object that should not be modified by the caller.  Unless you are attempting to maintain some type of compatibility with an external API, you should keep the use of pointer return-types to objects that can be modified later on.  Because of C++'s backwards-compatibility with C-style casting, it's too easy to cast away the protection of `const` when using pointer-types.  References on the other-hand can provide you much greater control over maintaining the `const`-ness of an object from function-call to function-call.  It requires an explicit `const_cast` operation in order to remove the `const`-ness of a constant-reference object (or some relatively obtuse C-style casts), where-as C-style casting can strip the constant nature of a pointer object by simply doing something like:

```
const int* test1() { static int a; return &a; }
void test2(int* a){}

const int* b = test();
test2((int*)b);
```

While the above doesn't pin-point the specific reason for your segmentation fault, I do believe the fact that you're modifying memory that was originally designated as constant signifies an underlying attribute of your `data` object that should not be changed, and/or may not be thread-safe, thus causing the opportunity for undefined behavior and seg-faults to occur.